# Redux Vuex NGRX for remote API read only data

Tags: vue.js, redux, vuex, ngrx, state-management

I need some help understanding the use of state management (Redux/Vuex/NGRX) for querying remote APIs that contain mostly read-only data for presentation.  This is opposed to in-app state such as keeping track of favorites, my shopping cart, etc.  Most examples on state management are pretty basic and don't explain this.

Let's say I need data from a remote data store/API that in some cases I may not be the owner of, or they may be part of a long-running asynchronous process.  Is local state management an appropriate use?

Example: A remote NEWS feed API.  Not likely an application user would ever 'write' to it.  It may contain thousands of news stories.  Would it be appropriate to use a more traditional service to fetch stuff from the API for this, but use state management for local in-app state, or is it really better to go all-in on state management and I am just missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: The usefulness of global app state isn't tied to whether you write to it or not.

Comment: Thanks. Simplifying the question perhaps. Would you store all things in state then? Not a bifrucated solution where some state is in app state and some data you just fetch from remote services when you need ?

Comment: It looks like a focus on a wrong thing. Data needs to be stored somewhere after it's fetched in order to be used, and it actually doesn't matter if it originates from api or somewhere else. It will be stored in either global state or local component state (this is not what you called local in the question). So basically this is global vs local state, which was discussed a lot on SO, and the points are very similar for all frameworks.

Comment: Basically if you can benefit from reusing a state between components or instances of the same component, or access it outside them (in a router or a modal), that's a case for global state. Even if you can't, you can probably go with global state because it's a way to organize business logic and debug it, but that's subjective. It doesn't matter if it's writable or comes from api. You may also want to check things like React Query which is a form of state management but tailored for data, with advanced caching capabilities